# Error is Expecting less columns than returned

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_user_info ( u_email VARCHAR, u_password VARCHAR, p_name VARCHAR )
RETURNS TABLE(
    user_id             int,                
    given_name          varchar(55),
    family_name         varchar(55),
    password            varchar(255),
    email               varchar(255),
    date_of_birth       date
)
AS $$
BEGIN
    -- If a player display player_name and team_id
    IF p_name != '' THEN
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT player.user_id, player.given_name, player.family_name, player.password, player.email, player.date_of_birth,
        player.player_name AS player_name, player.team_id AS team_id FROM player
        WHERE player.email = u_email and player.password = u_password;
    -- If not a player then display usual table
    ELSE
        RETURN QUERY
        SELECT * FROM "user"
        WHERE "user".email = u_email and "user".password = u_password;
    END IF;
END $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Get user info with arguments - email, password and player_name. If not a player pass '' as player_name
SELECT get_user_info('tomtom@hotmail.com', 'tommy12', 'tomkilla'); -- Player
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  structure of query does not match function result type
DETAIL:  Number of returned columns (8) does not match expected column count (6).
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_user_info(character varying,character varying,character varying) line 5 at RETURN QUERY
SQL state: 42804
```

Just wondering why I'm getting this error? I swear I had it working earlier but now its not >_> if I do a spectator the query works

Comment: If you want to delete your question, then "close" it, but don't remove the actual text

Answer (score 1):

Your function is expecting only 6 columns to be returned

```
(
    user_id             int,                
    given_name          varchar(55),
    family_name         varchar(55),
    password            varchar(255),
    email               varchar(255),
    date_of_birth       date
)
```

But your select statement is returning 8 columns

```
player.user_id, player.given_name, player.family_name, player.password, player.email, player.date_of_birth,player.player_name AS player_name, player.team_id AS team_id
```

you can add these 2 columns in return statement as

```
(
    user_id             int,                
    given_name          varchar(55),
    family_name         varchar(55),
    password            varchar(255),
    email               varchar(255),
    date_of_birth       date,
    player_name         <type>,
    team_id             <type>
)
```

and in else statement you are returning all columns from users table, You may specify the columns that's need to be returned else you may face problem there as well.

Comment: so how would i specify the columns twice? As I only want to show the other two columns when it is a player not a spectator. They inherit from "user" table.

Comment: No you cannot do that. You can return `SETOF RECORD` from function for dynamic number of columns returned but you would have to specify column in the select. More on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218862/how-return-dynamic-number-of-columns-in-function

Comment: so why does the "player.player_name AS player_name, player.team_id AS team_id" not work? I thought that adds in psuedo columns?

Comment: for that to work u have to return `SETOF RECORD` not `TABLE`.